# How to create a WAR in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a Java project that has multiple subprojects. It currently uses gradle however we are now trying to move to Bazel.

How can I create a WAR file using Bazel build?

Could not find any example online.

The only thing I found is this repo:
https://github.com/bmuschko/rules_java_war

However it hasn't had any activity in over 3 years. I am not sure if it is still valid.

Comment: Yes it is valid. You can implement using a custom Bazel rule with https://github.com/bmuschko/rules_java_war

Answer (score 2):

In Bazel, you can create a WAR (Web Application Archive) file by defining a war target in your BUILD file. Here are the steps to create a WAR in Bazel:

1. Define a Java library target: If your WAR project contains Java code, you will need to define a Java library target in your BUILD file. This target specifies the location of your Java code and its dependencies.

```
java_library(
    name = "my_java_library",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = [        "//third_party/library:library",    ],
)
```

2. Define a filegroup target: If your WAR project contains any web application resources (such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files), you will need to define a filegroup target in your BUILD file. This target specifies the location of your web application resources.

```
filegroup(
    name = "my_web_resources",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/webapp/**/*"]),
)
```

3. Define a war target: Finally, you will need to define a war target in your BUILD file. This target specifies the location of your Java library and web application resources and creates the WAR file.

```
war(
    name = "my_war_file",
    libs = [":my_java_library"],
    resources = [":my_web_resources"],
    webxml = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml",
)
```

These are the basic steps for creating a WAR in Bazel. You can find additional information and best practices for creating WAR files in Bazel in the Bazel documentation. Note that the exact steps for creating a WAR in Bazel will depend on the specific architecture and technology stack of your project.